# Rails - How can I load a (valid) file from Webrick into a HTML5 video element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, html5-video, webrick

This code, from a file on my desktop, does not work:

```
<video src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/attachable/108/original/501Spotlight_PSUB.mov" controls autobuffer="autobuffer" type="video/quicktime" height="300" width="400"></video>
```

Here are the network transaction(s?) for the video transfer:

http://project.touchstudios.net/public/broken.png

The video element returns code 4 - MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED

This DOES work:

```
<video src="501Spotlight_PSUB.mov" controls autobuffer="autobuffer" type="video/quicktime"height="300" width="400"></video> <!-- video file is on desktop too -->
```

And here's the output for that:

http://project.touchstudios.net/public/working.png

(note that pending status seems to be displayed permanently)

I've fiddled around with Unicorn as well, and had similar problems. Maybe I didn't configure it properly.

assets/attachable is in my public folder. My impression is that rails itself is barely (or not) involved with transferring/processing those files.

I've added this line to config/initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "video/quicktime", :mov
```

I have this output from rails console:

```
>> Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension("mov")
=> #<Mime::Type:0x1020992e8 @string="video/quicktime", @synonyms=[], @symbol=:mov>
>> MIME::Types.type_for("asdf.mov").to_s
=> "video/quicktime"
```

Is WEBrick (1.3.1) to blame here? This exact question was asked before, but not resolved. I'm hoping to be able to provide more detail.

Any guesses? I can answer any question that'll help narrow this down.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, couldn't resolve this directly, but it works with Passenger: sudo gem install passenger --- passenger start (in project directory)